Backward Stepwise Regression for Fixed Effects in R
I'm trying to run a backward stepwise regression in R, but I might not know how to accomplish what I want.
This is an example of what I want to do:
Using the Iris dataset, I have a simple regression with fixed effects for Species:
lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width + Sepal.Width + Sepal.Length + as.factor(Species), data = iris)

I want to run something similar to a backward stepwise regression, but instead of removing variables, I want to remove categories (subsampling) from Species until my variables stop being significant.
How could I do that?

What does "I want to remove factors/categories from Species" mean? Do you want to merge categories (how?) or do you want to remove categories (by subsetting the data)? In the latter case you can't compare model fits (with significance tests or AIC) because the models won't be fit to the same data (and thus have incomparable likelihoods or residual variance).

Sorry, I want to subset the data - removing categories. I'm also only interested in the coefficient and its significance (I edited the question to make it clearer).
I managed to achieve the result I wanted with couple of loops, but I hoped for a more simple solution

That doesn't strike me as sensible and, of course, no comparison of model statistics is possible then.

In my case, I'd want to use this for a model with fixed effects for countries (something like 50+ countries). The idea is to check the robustness of my model and identify if some countries are influencing the effect.

Understanding robustness is a reasonable goal but it would seem to make sense to refit the model with individual countries dropped from the full model, rather than doing backward stepwise ...

But that's precisely what the code below is doing. It fits the model multiple times, each time dropping one of the countries. I think the problem was how I phrased my question. The idea was something "closer" to what a backward stepwise regression would do, but I couldn't actually put what I wanted into words.

I achieved the results I wanted with a couple of loops, but I hoped for a more efficient or simpler solution:
# Install and load necessary packages
pacman::p_load(dplyr, broom, writexl, beepr)

# Assuming iris is the dataframe 
# Model: lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width + Sepal.Width + Sepal.Length + as.factor(Species), data = iris)

# Define a function to run the regression model and return the results
run_model <- function(data, formula) {
  model <- lm(formula, data = data)
  # Extract model summary
  summary_model <- summary(model)
  # Extract coefficients, p-values, and other details
  coefficients <- summary_model$coefficients
  # Return a list with AIC and coefficients
  return(list(coefficients = coefficients))
}

# Store initial model results for the full model
full_model_results <- run_model(iris, 
                                Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width + Sepal.Width + Sepal.Length + as.factor(Species))

# Initialize a list to store results
results <- list(full_model = full_model_results)

# Get the unique levels of Species
species <- unique(iris$Species)

# Loop to drop one cat at a time
for (i in 0:(length(species)-1)) {
  # Subset data to exclude the current set of species
  subset_data <- dplyr::filter(iris, !Species %in% species[1:i])
  
  # Check if there are at least two levels of Species left
  if (length(unique(subset_data$Species)) < 2) {
    next
  }
  
  # Run the regression model on the subset data
  current_results <- run_model(subset_data, 
                               Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width + Sepal.Width + Sepal.Length + as.factor(Species))
  
  # Store the results with a descriptive name
  results[[paste0("drop_", i, "_species")]] <- current_results
}

# Format and display the results in a more readable format
formatted_results <- lapply(results, function(res) {
  list(
    Coefficients = as.data.frame(res$coefficients)
  )
})


Please don't do this. Stepwise procedures to find a "best" model are almost universally bad.
See the following for further reading (on CrossValidated):
Algorithms for automatic model selection
Understanding why stepwise selecton based on p-values is bad
Why are p-values misleading after performing a stepwise selection?
How much do we know about p-hacking "in the wild"?
ASA discusses limitations of p-values - what are the alternatives?
And on external sites/blogs:
Stopping Stepwise
Why is stepwise regression criticized?
What are some of the problems with stepwise regression?
Why we hate stepwise regression
And a few journal articles:
Henderson, D.A. and Denison, D.R., 1989. Stepwise regression in social and psychological research. Psychological Reports, 64(1), pp.251-257.
https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.2466/pr0.1989.64.1.251
Hurvich, C.M. & Tsai, C.L. (1990) The impact of model selection on inference in linear regression. American Statistician, 44, 214–217.
https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00031305.1990.10475722
Stephens, P.A., Buskirk, S.W., Hayward, G.D. & Martinez del Rio, C. (2005) Information theory and hypothesis testing: a call for pluralism. Journal of Applied Ecology, 42, 4–12.
https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.1365-2664.2005.01002.x
Steyerberg, E.W., Eijkemans, M.J.C. & Habbema, J.D.F. (1999) Stepwise selection in small data sets: a simulation study of bias in logistic regression analysis. Journal of Clinical Epidemiology, 52, 935–942.
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0895435699001031
Thompson, B., 2001. Significance, effect sizes, stepwise methods, and other issues: Strong arguments move the field. The Journal of Experimental Education, 70(1), pp.80-93.
https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00220970109599499
Whittingham, M.J., Stephens, P.A., Bradbury, R.B. and Freckleton, R.P., 2006. Why do we still use stepwise modelling in ecology and behaviour?. Journal of animal ecology, 75(5), pp.1182-1189.
https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.1365-2656.2006.01141.x
Woodside, A.G., 2016. The good practices manifesto: Overcoming bad practices pervasive in current research in business. Journal of Business Research, 69(2), pp.365-381.
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0148296315004142

These are great suggestions, Robert! Thanks!
I replied to Ben's comments above, and I think that I had some difficulties in putting what I wanted to do into words, but the idea was to fit the model multiple times, each time dropping one of the countries. I thought the logic of a backward stepwise regression would be closer to what I wanted... either way, thanks for the suggestions!
